# UIImagePickerController in an existing UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

Is there a way to push the UIImagePickerController in an existing UIPopoverController's navigation controller?

What I know is that you have to create a new popover and add the UIImagePickerController in it. But I have an existing popover with its navigation controller that should present the image picker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `setContentViewController:animated:` on `UIPopoverController`

Comment: This works great! How do I go back, by adding a cancel/back button to the `UIImagePicker` navigation stack?

Comment: @AdamCarter

What I did to "go back" , Is just to set the ContentViewController to the first view controller that was in the UIPopoverController.

I dont think you can "go back" (or dismiss) in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is no because the image picker brings its own navigation controller. And nesting two nav controllers does probably not work.