# UIImagePickerController and External display

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I am writing an iPad kiosk-type application that allows a visitor to record a video using the front facing camera and view existing videos in the Camera Roll that are targeting an External monitor. I am just learning XCode, and working in Xcode 4.4.1 targeting iOS 5. It seems like a lot has changed recently and this is making it much harder to learn so I am trying to keep things as simple as possible, that's why I am using UIImagePicker.

Everything is working as I wish, with one exception – I am not able to toggle between the external display and the iPad as I want. When the user records a video, it is full screen on the iPad. That's fine, however after they stop recording, the video is immediately sent to the external display for approval and a placeholder image is left in the UIPopover.  What I would rather see/do is either keep the video preview full screen on the iPad, or target the video to the UIPopover.

The reason is that the external display is not easily viewable from where the user is accessing the iPad. Therefore, they are being asked to approve (click Use) on something they can't really see. It would be much better to keep it on the iPad. The code below is what I have used to allow recording.

Everything else works great, I want the user to select videos from the Library and display on the External monitor, and since that's the default behavior it works fine.

The closest answer I could find so far is this: [UIImagePickerController in an existing UIPopoverController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627498/uiimagepickercontroller-in-an-existing-uipopovercontroller)

Is there a simple way to disable the external display or keep the video preview from being sent?

```
   - (IBAction)useCameraRoll:(id)sender
{
    if([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
        {

            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
            [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

            imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

            self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
            //self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] setContentViewController:animated];

            self.popoverController.delegate = self;

            [self.popoverController
             presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

            newMedia = NO;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I think the answer below only details how to setup an external device.  I also have an app that draws to an external monitor, but when a user uses the UIImagePickerController, it draws previews straight over whatever the external device is supposed to be drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentally, I have been working on a similar kiosk app with an iPad. In my case it utilizes some Augmented Reality to show relevant content on the external display. I use the iPad screen as a configuration panel for the augmented reality experience.

Best way, that I found, to approach this, would be to use separate windows with the two UIScreens for each of the displays. This enables you to craft the experience properly. I am not sure if you are using this approach already, but if you aren't, then this is the way to go.

To get started you can read the [ExternalDisplay](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ExternalDisplay/Introduction/Intro.html) code sample. From the excerpt:

From the ExternalDisplay sample code in the iOS Developer Library:

> To display content on an external display, do the following:
>
> 1. Use the screens class method of the UIScreen class to determine if an external display is available.
> 2. If an external screen is available, get the screen object and look at the values in its availableModes  property. This property contains
>      the configurations supported by the screen.
> 3. Select the UIScreenMode object corresponding to the desired resolution and assign it to the currentMode  property of the screen
>      object.
> 4. Create a new window object (UIWindow) to display your content.
> 5. Assign the screen object to the screen property of your new window.
> 6. Configure the window (by adding views or setting up your OpenGL ES rendering context).
> 7. Show the window.

Also, the [UIScreen](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html) documentation is quitehelpful.